# Is there a technical implementation in c++, the modification of struct members is to modify the bound data, and this binding relationship is dynamic?

Tags: c++

For example, if I have global variables:

```
int a;
int b;
```

I define that I can return a `struct`, I hope the members of the structure are bound to the global variables, and my modification to the members of the structure is to modify the global a, b. The code like:

```
struct bind
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
Bind getBind()
{
    Bind bind;
    band to a; // could be other variable, e.g. c
    band to b; // could be other variable, e.g. d
    return bind;
}
```

**Note that it is not a simple reference**, I may want to return the `struct` bound to `c,d` the next time I invoke `getBind()`.

Background introduction:

1. collect data scattered around as a struct in a caller-unaware
   way.
2. can return a const struct, caller can't modify its member
3. avoid modify member inconsciently by copy obj

I'm very puzzled, for the underlying language of C++, this should be easy to implement, but there seems to be no such funcation. Maybe I don't know, I hope so and get the answer here.

Comment: Why not have `band` store references instead of values?

Comment: And why is that not a simple reference?

Comment: c does not have c++ references. Please only tag the lagnauge you are using

Comment: Make the members of `band` be references, and then have reference parameters in `getBand` so you can pass to `getBand` which objects you want the band to bind to.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think there might be some solutions from c.

Comment: @NathanOliver could you give your code, I don't know exactly what timing you bind?

Comment: @Crawl.W yes in C you can use pointers, in C++ as well, but in general the solutions in C will not be the same as the solutions in C++, because they are two different languages. Please only tag the language you are using

Comment: it is not clear why it cannot be references. Can you show the code that is using references and explain the problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use references:

```
#include <iostream>

int a,b,c,d;

struct Bind {
    int& ref1;
    int& ref2;
};

Bind getBind(bool flag){
    if (flag) return {a,b};
    else return {c,d};
}

// ... or ...
Bind getBind(int& a,int& b){
    return {a,b};
}

int main() {
    auto x = getBind(true);
    x.ref1 = 42;
    x.ref2 = 101;
    auto y = getBind(false);
    y.ref1 = 0;
    y.ref2 = 1;

    auto z = getBind(a,b);
    std::cout << z.ref1 << " " << z.ref2 << "\n";
    auto w = getBind(c,d);
    std::cout << w.ref1 << " " << w.ref2 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
42 101
0 1
```

However, it is not quite clear what you want to achieve. Global variables are better to be avoided in the first place and using reference as memebrs has certain implications, though if thats what you want then maybe its just fine.

Comment: Awesome, initializer list as return value to construct struct with reference members is the solution I am looking for! I'm collecting data scattered around as a struct in a caller-unaware way. A fly in the ointment, how to return a `const struct`?

Comment: Callers cannot modify its members, direct `const` decorated is invalid, why?

Comment: And reference struct copy is a problem.

Comment: @Crawl.W Sorry its not clear what you mean. Why is it a "problem"? What do you mean with "direct `const` decorated is invalid" ?

Comment: you want something like this https://godbolt.org/z/EKj9scxcf ?

Comment: @Crawl.W Perhaps add a code example in your question

Comment: Why is it a "problem"? refer to No.3 in Background introduction. What do you mean with "direct const decorated is invalid" ? yes, you can try `const Bind getBind(bool flag)`.

Comment: are myabe you want just a pair: https://godbolt.org/z/x3rYjb99E

Comment: Should the pair be <int, int> or contain references or be const/contain const int?

Comment: @Crawl.W the crux of your issue seems to be const-correctness. Not sure how to explain it, but the point is that you cannot have all you want in one. You can have a `Bind` that allows the caller to modify the members and a `constant_Bind` that does not allow the caller to modify the members. Returning a `const Bind` does not help when the members are references (or pointers) because the caller can copy a `const` return value and then modify that copy as much as they want.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Would pointers or references to a const int work? Or is it about afterwards copying the value itself? If this should be prevented, then encapsulating/hiding the value and providing functions like 'printing' could be an option. But then somebody could grab the screen and read out the values and copy them. Or directly accessing the memory of the encapsulating object. Perhaps storing them in another process with memory protection?

Comment: @Sebastian sorry I dont understand what you mean. grab the screen?!? OP seems to want modifications sometimes and some times not. This can be done by providing two structs with different semantics as I already pointed out above. https://godbolt.org/z/EKj9scxcf

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Agree with your statement. Earlier, I was already implementing two kinds of `Bind`, like `struct Bind{int a; int b;}` and `struct BindRef{int &a; int &b;}`, by return from diffrent funcation.

Comment: @Crawl.W its a common pattern. Consider for example iterators and const_iterators. They are two distinct types, because thats the way to provide two different semantics

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number With mentioning grabbing the screen I wanted to exaggerate that it won't be easily possible to prevent copying and modifying the copy (you wrote "because the caller can copy a const return value and then modify that copy as much as they want"). We would always want/need the caller to play fair.

Comment: There would be possibilities to make different grades of difficulty for the caller. a) make it const => copy + modify  b) hide the value as private and provide utility functions like print => caller could grab screen or directly read the memory layout of the object including its private instances c) use another process on the system to store the object

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your unreserved help, `const_iterators` is the best practice. I accept c++ is not perfect, some compromises are needed, my heart is no longer so stifled, lol.

Comment: @Crawl.W its not so much because C++ isnt perfect. The thing is that one can copy a constant object to get a non-constant object. Constness does not transitively apply to all copies. This can only work when you make the members const, but then they cannot be mutated anymore

Comment: And if the members are publicly accessible they can even be copied, if they are const.